# Python3 unexpected return value of to_bytes

Tags: python-3.x, byte

For some reason `to_bytes` doesn't work correctly for me.

```
x = 0x123456
xb = x.to_bytes((x.bit_length() + 7)//8, 'big')
print(xb) # returns b'\x124V'
```

However, judging by https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes, I would have expected to get `b'\x12\x34\x56'`. Can someone please tell me where my misunderstanding is?

Comment: depending on what number I use I get all kinds of weird characters. This is really strange, because even when you put it into a byte array it still has those characters! but indexing the array does produce the correct value

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent, so you are getting the right result. The '4' and 'V' are the character equivalents to their ASCII hex representations 34 and 56, respectively. It would seem that Python is shortening the byte this way, but I don't know the reason why.